# Customizing Laravel validation JSON message format - Laravel

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-validation, laravel-formrequest

I'm trying to figure out how to customize the Form requests to validate

By default Laravel gives a good enough JSON format for validation errors but what if we want to customize it?

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "Please enter email address."
        ],
        "password": [
            "Please enter password."
        ]
    }
}
```

for a particular project, we decided to change the format to this.

```
{
    "success": false,
    "errors": [
        {
            "email": "Please enter an email address."
        },
        {
            "password": "Please enter a password."
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help would be great.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.

```
public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ValidationException) {
        // Custom response
        $response = [
            'success' => false,
            'error' => $e->errors()
        ];
        
        return response()->json($response, 422);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: Put this code in app/Exception/Handler.php